# ASP.NET MVC : access container from EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates, modelmetadataprovider, asp.net-mvc-uihint

I have a view model **AssetFreezeViewModel.cs** that contains the following property :

```
public AssetFreezeAccountBalanceViewModel AccountBalanceInfo { get; set; }
```

I have a view **Details.cshtml** based on the ViewModel above with that line :

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.AccountBalanceInfo)
```

In \Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\ , I have a template  **AssetFreezeAccountBalanceViewModel.cshtml** whose name is the same as the type of AccountBalanceInfo that is AssetFreezeAccountBalanceViewModel (by convention)

In that EditorTemplate, I have :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeviseId)
```

In **AssetFreezeAccountBalanceViewModel.cs**, I have :

```
[UIHint("DropDownList")]
public Int16? DeviseId { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DeviseIdList { get; set; }
```

Finally, in \Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\ I have **DropDownList.cshtml** (applied to DeviseId by convention) :

```
@model dynamic
@{
    var propertyNameLookup = this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName + "List";
    var property = this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Container.GetType().GetProperty(propertyNameLookup);
...
}
```

When the code hits @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeviseId) , we enter  DropDownList.cshtml where **Container** is null then crash.

How can I access Container (= parent) from that EditorTemplate which is 2 level down from its view ?

Comment: At the top of AssetFreezeAccountBalanceViewModel.cshtml, do you have @model AssetFreezeAccountBalanceViewModel ?

Answer (score 0):

I just added `@model AssetFreezeAccountBalanceViewModel` At the top of `AssetFreezeAccountBalanceViewModel.cshtml`

Here is a [sample project](https://app.box.com/s/kwibz23gal3oxskvyd5jz7eh98iqcod4).

Hope that helps.